# C# winform application doesn't wait for all operations to finish

Tags: c#, winforms, events, fft, ui-thread

I'm developing a simple application that when I press the button "obtain readings", is going to listen to the microphone and process the fundamental frequency. My problem is that when I create the data to record in the DB the value is 0. If I debug the solution I can see that after the Insert the program is still processing the frequencies.

As a basis for my application I'm using the code available on Codeproject (FTGuitarTuner).

```
    private void getReading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        EndTime = StartTime.AddSeconds(3);
        TotalMillisegundos = EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        tmr.Start();
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
        StartListenning(device);
        while (DateTime.Now <= this.EndTime)
        {
            isListenning = true;
            tmr_Tick(sender, e);
        }
        StopListenning();
        /*Insert na BD*/
        insertReadingBD(sender, e);
        getBySessaoToolStripButton2_Click(sender, e);
    }
```

The other 3 functions are

```
           private void StopListenning()
    {
        isListenning = false;
        frequencyInfoSource.Stop();
        frequencyInfoSource.FrequencyDetected -= new EventHandler<FrequencyDetectedEventArgs>(frequencyInfoSource_FrequencyDetected);
        frequencyInfoSource = null;
    }
    private void StartListenning(SoundCaptureDevice device)
    {
        isListenning = true;
        frequencyInfoSource = new SoundFrequencyInfoSource(device);
        frequencyInfoSource.FrequencyDetected += new EventHandler<FrequencyDetectedEventArgs>(frequencyInfoSource_FrequencyDetected);
        frequencyInfoSource.Listen();
    }
    void frequencyInfoSource_FrequencyDetected(object sender, FrequencyDetectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<FrequencyDetectedEventArgs>(frequencyInfoSource_FrequencyDetected), sender, e);
            iEscreve = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Frequency > 25.000 && e.Frequency < 4500.000)
            {
                frequencies.Add(e.Frequency);
                updateFreqTxt(e.Frequency);
            }
        }
   }
```

My question is, how can I sync the events in a way that he only inserts in the DB after all processing is done?

Thank's!

Comment: Don't use `invoke` use `Task` and `Wait()`. This will prevent the code that might be running asynchroniously from returning to the caller...

Comment: How can I use Task? Is it in this line if (InvokeRequired) { BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<FrequencyDetectedEventArgs>(frequencyInfoSource_FrequencyDetected), sender, e); iEscreve = false; } Thank's.

Comment: I have such little time now. I will reply in detail this evening... Sorry.

Comment: Your `while` loop keeps your insert from being executed, so that is part of your consideration. I don't really get the use of your `while` loop? It is for determining when all the processing is done, isn't it? So why doesn't it work?

Comment: The problem is that it writes to the database before _frequencyInfoSource_FrequencyDetected_ finishes. The While is just for the progress bar, since I'm capturing audio from the microphone in real time, the system should capture for 3 sec's